# import date from csv file into mysql using bash

Tags: mysql, linux

I have this pattern 27-FEB-17 in a csv file. how can i keep this format on mysql using DATE and not CHAR?

## !/bin/bash

mysql --user= --password= --local_infile=1 models -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/27022017.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines"

thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL DATE type format is YYYY-MM-DD. You can't keep that formatting under the DATE type.

If your goal is not to iterate and transform the dates formatting you could look into triggers to post-process the string values into a proper DATE